# Add objects to a vector pointed to by another object of the same class

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, operator-overloading

As part of a C++ assignment to learn more about pointers and objects, I have a class that represents family members. One of the parameters is a vector pointer, "kids", which should contain objects of that same class. I've been told to use operator overloading with '<' to add newly-created objects to the 'kids' field of another object. Here's what I currently have:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Family{
public: 
   string name; 
   int age; 
   //An object pointer of Family to represent a spouse 
   Family * spouse; 
   //a vector pointer of Family to represent children 
   vector<Family>* kids;

   /** 
   * A constructor that takes 4 arguments 
   * @param n  takes default 'unknown' 
   * @param a  takes default 18
   * @param s  takes default NULL
   * @param v  takes default NULL
   */ 
   Family( string n="Unknown", int a=18, Family * s=NULL,vector<Family> * v=NULL){
       name=n; 
       age=a; 
       kids=new vector<Family>; 
       spouse=s; 
   }
   /**2pts
    * Create a method that overloads < 
    * The method will add a Family object to the list of children
    * @param a Family object 
    */
   int kCount = 0;
   void operator<(Family f) {
       (*kids)[kCount] = f;
   }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Declaring an object F using a name and age=35 representing a female.
      Family F("Nicky",35);
    //Declaring an object M using a name, age =39 and spouse being the previous object
      Family  M("Nick",39,&F);

    Family c0("Ricky", 15);
    Family c1("Bicky", 12);
    Family c2("Dicky", 9);
    Family c3("Micky", 6);
    //2pts Add the kids to M using the operator <
    M < c0; 
    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to run this, I get a segfault. I'm still very inexperienced with pointers, so I really don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Using `operator<` to insert objects is rather obscure.  It is way more common to use `operator<<`, although you need to use what you've been told to use.  You might want to recheck the documentation for `vector` for how to add elements to a vector.

Comment: Why is your vector object a pointer? What do you expect to accomplish by making it a pointer, that must be explicitly allocated and deallocated, all that extra work, what does that do for you (this doesn't directly have anything to do with the simple bug that's causing this crash, but it adds unnecessary syntax and complications, that obfuscated the underlying problem)?

Comment: Sam, I really wish I knew. My professor is... interesting. I just have to work with what I can.

Comment: Just to clarify: is your professor explicitly instructing you to use a pointer, what exactly are your professor's instructions, here? It is certainly possible that your professor is an incompentent C++ instructor, there's plenty of evidence of incompetent C++ instructors, around here, but it's just as likely that you simply misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

After a tip from one of the commenters, I looked up some info about adding objects to vectors and found a solution.

```
void operator<(Family f) {
    (*kids).push_back(f);
}

// in main()...

Family c0("Ricky", 15);
M < c0;
```

Thanks to 1201ProgramAlarm for the tip!